# How are you handling theme updates across multiple Shiny apps?

Tags: r, shiny

I have a general `shiny` question, rather than a specific call to help with code.

I've just finished creating a branded `shiny` template using a mix of `fresh` and some custom CSS. It's branded and looks sharp for the dashboards I'm building for my organisation. However, I've got one eye on how to maintain the look and feel of our dashboards as our analytics team continues to grow and mature. When we have 50 apps deployed and we want to change the theme, we will have to go through and update the code in 50 different shinyapps if we continue with the current method of `fresh` and custom CSS in `www/`.

Does anyone have experience in centralising themes? Perhaps serving CSS from somewhere external to Shiny and calling that at the start of `app.R`? This would likely require me to unify `fresh` and my additional custom CSS into a single .css file, but that's something I'm willing to do.

Alternatively, perhaps someone clever has already developed a package to solve this problem?

Any general pointers warmly received.

Comment: Why not packing the template with some other commonly needed code into a package? You provide the package at a central location and whenerver there is some change to the theme you update the package. You could even go so far as to automatically look for an update of the package as soon as the app starts.

Comment: Yeah, that's not a bad shout. I did consider this yesterday evening as I was mulling things over some more. I'm writing a package for common functions anyway (things like org-specific database connections etc.) so adding the template into this as well would seem to be a sensible solution to the problem.

Comment: How about making a directory of your styles outside your apps and making soft links in all apps  `www` pointing to the style directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who might be interested, I built the theme into a package I was developing. Within my *package's* root dir, I added an `inst` folder and, inside that, a `www` dir. I added the organisation logo and some extra CSS that couldn't be easily configured with `{fresh}`.

To set the theme, I created a function like this:

```
set_theme<-function(){

  theme<-fresh::create_theme(

    fresh::adminlte_color(
      light_blue = "#383F48",
      aqua = "#094357",
      green = "#094357",
      blue = "#383F48"
    ),

    fresh::adminlte_global(
      box_bg = "#FFFFFF",
      info_box_bg = "#D1E0E5"
    ),

    fresh::adminlte_vars(
      "sidebar-width" = "275px",
      "sidebar-dark-bg" = "#3A3F46",
      "sidebar-dark-hover-color" = "#FFB151",
      "btn-border-radius" = "1px"
    )
  )

  shiny::addResourcePath('www', system.file("www", package = "myPackage"))

  return(theme)

}
```

I used `shiny::addResourcePath` to create a resource path to link the package's `inst/www` folder to the project within which `myPackage::set_theme()` is called. Then, within my Shiny dashboards:

```
library(myPackage)

theme <- myPackage::set_theme()

ui<-(
    fresh::use_theme(theme)
    ...
    tags$head(tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = 
    "www/style.css"))
    ...
)
```

Make note of the `www/` in the href argument. If you were to keep these files 'locally' within your Shiny app, you'd create a `www` dir in root and forego the `www/` prefix. When calling files from your package, simply include the `www/`